# Leafletjs random markers

Tags: php, leaflet

Please can I get some help with creating an algorithm to place random markers inside a rectangle shape. The markers should also be at least x distance away from each other where possible. The algorithm should return possible co-ordinates.

Example:
I have a rectangle with the cords: 
[-337.243, -158] , [159.757, 1009]

And I am wishing to place 3 markers inside the box. 
Currently these cords are store in a database and I am trying to generate possible cords through PHP.